# How do I prove there is a homeomorphism between these two topological spaces?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $ X=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | |x| \leq 1 \} $with the induced euclidean topology $\tau$ and let $R$ be the equivalence relation $(x',y')R(x,y)$ if and only if $ y=y'=0$ or $(x',y')=(x,y)$.
Tell if the quotient space$(X/R,\tau/R)$ is homeomorphic to $Y_k =\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x^2-y^2 \leq k \}$ for $k=0$ and $k=1$

Can someone show how to do it?. I kow I have to use saturated sets somehow

This is the solution I was given, but there are many things I don't get.

> The function $f:X\rightarrow Y_0 $ defined by $f((x,y))=(xy,y)$is totally compatible, surjective and continuous. Besides it maps saturated open sets in open sets: In fact, an open set A is saturated iff it does not intersect $(-1,1)X\{O\}$ or if it contains it. In the first case  f is a homeomorphism of $ A$ with $f(A)$, in the second case there exist an $\epsilon$ such that $Q=(-1 ,1)  X  (-\epsilon , -\epsilon) \subseteq A $. Now  $f(Q)$ is an open set containing $O$ and $f(A)$ is open and $f_R$ is an homeomorphism.
>   All of this implies $(X/R-\{[O]\},\tau/R)$ is not connected, while  $Y_1$  remains connected if one removes one point.

*note : I couldn't found an english traslation for the concept of "totally compatible function". I am doing a literal traslation here, but the definition  is the following:

> Let f be a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$, and $R$ an equivalence relation. f is said to be compatible with $R$ if  $xRy$ implies $f(x)=f(y)$; $f$ is  said totally compatible if the implication is in both ways. This allow to define a function $f_R: X/R \rightarrow Y$, so that $f=f_R o \Pi $, dove $\Pi$ is the projection to the quotient space  $\Pi: X \rightarrow X/R$,
>
> Then there is a theorem which is what they used in the proof:
>   Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be compatible with $R$, then
>
> 1) $f_R$ is surjective iff $f$ is surjective
>
> 2)$f_R$ is injective iff $f$ is totally compatible
>
> 3)$f:(X,\tau)\rightarrow (Y,\tau')$ is continuous iff $f_R$ is continuous
>
> 4)f maps saturated open sets to open sets iff $f_R$ is an open function

what I don't understand in the proof:

1) How on earth could I have come up with the expresion for the function that maps $X$ to $Y_0$? I drew the sets, but still no clue

2) How do you prove f is surjective?

3) why is f(A) open? why are thet saying f is homeomorphism of A with f(A), we still need to prove that f is open

4) why does this imply $(X/R-\{[O]\},\tau/R)$ is not connected and why are they removing the class of the origin? by removing  a point aren't I changing all of the previous conclusions?

5) The last sentence of the proof refers to the case k=1, but all of the previous work was done for k=0, why are they assuming it is still valid or how do I prove it doing something similar for k=1? with k=1 $Y_1$ is now the region between an hyperbole and the function f defined at the beginning is not valid anymore

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** the quotient of a compact space is compact.

> However, the sequence $a_n := (n,n)$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is a subset of both $Y_0$ and $Y_1$, and so these spaces are not compact (here we are using that a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with the metric topology is compact iff it is closed and bounded).

Comment: si all of this referred to the case k=0? By close unit ball do you mean a closed neighborhood of radius 1 (in one dimension)? what do you mean with  the "wedge of two closed balls?

Comment: For some reason I misread and was thinking of showing $X \not \equiv X/R$. Still, the geometric intuition for $X/R$ is the same and a connectedness argument may help. My apologies, I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: I have typed the solution I was given, maybe you could help me understand it